# Insufficient permissions creating an Azure AD User/Group in Azure Synapse Serverless Database from CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: azure-synapse

During the setup of an Azure Synapse Serverless (OnDemand) SQL Database, I can't create an AAD User/Group because of insufficient permissions of the Server Identity. The query is executed token-based with a Service Principal from a CI/CD Pipeline (Azure DevOps).

I'm able to create a database using a Service Principal (which is in the AAD Group set as Synapse AD Administrator) with the following command:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -AccessToken (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://sql.azuresynapse.net).Token -ServerInstance "mysynapseworkspacename-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net" -Database "master" -Query "CREATE DATABASE [MYDB]"
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to create an AAD User/Group with the Service Principal, as the System Managed Identity of Synapse does not have sufficient permissions:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -AccessToken (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://sql.azuresynapse.net).Token -ServerInstance "mysynapseworkspacename-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net" -Database "MYDB" -Query "CREATE USER [My-User-Group] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER"
```

> Invoke-SqlCmd : Server identity does not have Azure Active Directory Readers permission. Please follow the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-service-principal

However, the Service Principal (with which the SQL command is executed) does have the necessary permissions (User.Read.All, GroupMember.Read.All, and Application.Read.ALL) and is added to the workspace as "Synapse SQL Administrator". Assigning the necessary permissions to the System Managed Identity (of the Synapse Workspace) is not possible, as the workspace (and its System Managed Identity) may not be persistent. As an alternative, there would be a User Assigned Managed Identity (with the necessary permissions) available within the Synapse Workspace.

Is there a possibility to connect or execute the command using the User Assigned Managed Identity or force to use the Service Principal for the creation of the AAD User/Group? How can I change the SQL "Server identity" to the User Assigned Managed Identity?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @MartinSmith: See https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2323, there is a discussion related about this issue. I was not able to solve the problem, but my alternative approach would have been to use the data pipeline with the Script Activity in Azure Synapse, or the approach with the SID as discussed in the link mentioned before.